# How to authenticate user from one site to other by link?

Tags: authentication

Suppose we have 2 sites, the hub and the client.

When we are registering on hub, the same user is automatically created on the client (same logins and passwords, but different hash passwords).

The user logs in on the hub, then the user clicks the link on the hub leading to the client. Is there any way to automatically authenticate this user on the client?

Most likely the hub and the client are available as subdomains to some domain, for example:

- hub.example.com
- client.example.com

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

First, let's be clear. You asked for "how to authorize a user", yet you're asking about "how to authenticate a user". These are VERY different things.

Assuming you meant authentication on both ends, this is something is a single sign-on solution does. You sign in once. You are signed in everywhere. There are plenty of solutions that can do this sort of thing for you.

Also, avoid duplicating passwords here and there. That contradicts the whole notion of single signon.

Comment: yea, i meant authentication (corrected). Thanks for answer. Now its more clearer for me after some research.